# jQuery ajax/post response encoding

Tags: jquery, encoding, json

I have a problem with json encoded information which loaded via ajax.

The PHP code (test.php):

```
<?php
  $val1 = 'Productmanager m / f';
  $val2 = 'test';
  $arr = array('first' => $val1, 'second' => $val2);
  echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

The JavaScript code inside a html file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post("test.php", function(data){
    var response = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(response.first);
    console.log(response.second);
  }
});
```

And the result in console looks like:

```
Productmanager&#x20;m&#x20;&#x2f;&#x20;f
```

and

```
test
```

Both files are UTF-8 encodet.

I´m realy dont know why and how to convert it back to a readable string.
You may have an idea how this can occur?

I have found no suitable solution at first go, just search&replace approaches.

Comment: Works fine after update!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the correct PHP header and decode the string:

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: application/json");
  $val1 = "Productmanager m / f";
  $val2 = "test";
  $arr = array("first" => $val1, "second" => $val2);
  echo json_encode($arr);
?>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.post("test.php", function(data){
        var response = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(htmlDecode(response.first));
        console.log(response.second);
      }
    });

function htmlEncode(value){
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}

</script>
```

Comment: ok, then i have to remove the "var response = $.parseJSON(data);" and the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(response.first);
                console.log(response.second);
        }
    });
});
```

You can set character encoding for ajax requests by using "contentType"

On your php side, your code must be like ;

```
<?php
  $val1 = 'Productmanager m / f';
  $val2 = 'test';
  $arr = array('first' => $val1, 'second' => $val2);
  echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Important note: JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE works with php 5.4.0!!

Comment: i try this, but have to remove the $.parseJSON, because the response is already parsed. the result was the same.

Comment: My webspace runs with PHP 5.3.10

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for your `test.php`

```
<?php
  $val1 = 'Productmanager m / f';
  $val2 = 'test';
  $arr = array('first' => $val1, 'second' => $val2);
  echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Comment: ends in an empty response :-/

Comment: you should have PHP version 5.4.0 to work with that JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option so can you just try to run yout test.php file and see what output it is giving